# How to display many different kinds of video material on one page?

Tags: lists, grid, video

Best examples and practices of displaying different video types (series, single program, short clip, trailer etc.) on one page.

How to indicate the differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to me too broad, but anyways I would try to indicate difference with Tag+Color (frame color)

- This way users may be able to associate colors with the given tag/category
- This way the difference among the videos will be clear for both new + regular users

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery Masonry and Wordpress (or any CMS) along with some Ajax.

Here's a site I'm working on. Just click on a box to see a video... (still work in progress).
http://keepskatinbro.com

Masonry (a jQuery plugin) allows you to organize a fluid grid dynamically written by Desandro:
http://desandro.com/

Here's a nice compilation of amazing examples using Masonry:
http://inspiredology.com/websites-leveraging-jquery-masonary/

Now, just imagine your videos displayed with Masonry. ;)